# Selecting text in mobile Safari on iPhone

Tags: javascript, iphone, copy, mobile-safari, zeroclipboard

I'm trying to make it easy for an iphone user to copy some text to the clipboard in mobile safari. As in the usual "touch-hold-copy". There is a specific bit of text I want to a user to copy. I have full choice of the html markup in which to wrap the text. How can I make it easy, rather than abitrary? For instance:

- Is there a way to "select all" the text upon touch-down using javascript? Then a user could just continue to touch-hold and then choose copy?
- Is there a way to bring up the "select all" option? Like you can when typing in a text box? After which they can choose copy?
- If there's no javascript solution, how can I arrange the html to help Safari select the right bit of text easily? As opposed to just a word, or a wrapping div?

I've tried onFocus="this.select()" for various elements, none seem to work. Also tried onClick.

Those who have tried to port a site that uses ZeroClipboard to the iPhone might have some ideas.

Cheers

Comment: I was trying for the same feature in my iPhone application. Anybody who has doubt regarding the feature can see the  it in the iPhone application "Opera".

Comment: Before the copy/paste were introduced to iOS, there was a java script bookmark named pastebud. Here is the youtube video of the java script in action

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_ybh573ZASc

The website http://www.pastebud.com/ is not working since apple introduced copy/paste in iOS.

Anybody with that java script can help us.

Answer (score 9):

instead of `this.select();` I used the following and it worked!

```
this.selectionStart=0;
this.selectionEnd=this.value.length;
```

Answer (score 7):

The magic sauce for me was the combination of these three:

```
onFocus="this.selectionStart=0; this.selectionEnd=this.value.length;" <!-- for big screens -->

onTouchEnd="this.selectionStart=0; this.selectionEnd=this.value.length;" <!-- for small screens -->

onMouseUp="return false" <!-- to stop the jitters -->
```

Comment: This worked for me with onClick instead of onFocus/onTouchEnd. onMouseUp was important

Answer (score 4):

Try ontouchstart instead of onfocus. Onfocus fires approx. 500ms after ontouchend, same as onclick, onmousedown, and onmouseup. See https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006511-SW7 for more details on mouse events.

Answer (score 2):

I have run into the same problem. The onfocus event is the right one to trap (ontouchstart isn't triggered if you use the iphone keyboard [next]/[prev] buttons.) If you put an alert(); in your onfocus="" handler, you'll see the alert box pop up. The problem is this.select(); I still haven't found an answer to this, but when/if I do, I'll post it here.

Comment: I've had the same issue. focus is the right event to trap, definitely. I think for a minor usability enhancement like this, I'm OK chalking it up to broken mobile safari and letting them fix it.