# iPhone iWebKit Copy to Clipboard

Tags: javascript, iphone, webkit

Just a general question.

Is it possible to copy text in Mobile Safari to the clipboard with some use of iWebkit JS?
(Without the users holding down text, and selecting Copy)

Similar to the Copy to Clipboard function that IE has on the PC.

Thanks.

Edit: 
This applies to just specific text, not the entire document. Example: a value in a text box.
And on Mobile Safari, its only non-local documents.

Comment: Welcome, Moe- could you provide a little more specifics- for example, is it a local or internet file you're viewing? Are you trying to copy all text on a page, or just some of it?

Comment: this question might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1899421/selecting-text-in-mobile-safari-on-iphone

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible. Desktop browsers usually support copying to the clipboard through Adobe Flash; such solution is not available on Mobile Safari.